# referencing a text file in yaml

Tags: file, yaml, substitution

I have a yaml file with one of the values >2000 lines. adding a 2k line to config is not helping to have a clean and clear to read config file. Is it possible to move the 2k lines into a text file and references the content of the file as value when reading the yaml

Current setup

```
curated:
    xform1: 
        case when A=B then C else D end
    xform2:
        case ....
        ...............
        ..............
        ................
        2000k lines
        end
```

Desired

```
curated:
    xform1: 
        case when A=B then C else D end
    xform2:xform2.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Not with pure YAML semantic.

If you are writing the loading code, you can of course define a local tag:

```yaml
curated:
  xform1:
    case when A=B then C else D end
  xform2: !file xform2.txt
```

When loading, you can implement the local tag `!file` as loading the referenced file. How to do this depends on the YAML implementation you're using; it will likely call this *registering a custom constructor*.

If you do *not* have any control over the loading code, it's not possible unless that code provides a way to do it. Some tools using YAML preprocess it with a templating engine which may allow it.

Depending on a setup, preprocessing the YAML with a templating engine yourself and then feeding the result into the tool loading the YAML might be a viable solution.